Can MSK and CPFSK modulation schemes have different modulation orders?
MSK can have

Modulation order M = 2
Modulation index h = 1/2
overlap factor L = 1

The question is can MSK have:

Modulation order M=4 OR 8 etc?

similarly what about CPFSK?
